# Login form fails when submit button has no name

Tags: curl

I want to make a login form to login to a web, but something is wrong.

When I copy default form from the site, it works. It has a submit btn and has no name just a value. When I change value it does not work. I want to know how the input can be sent without any name.

```
<form id="frm-12827221184c74c9466e522" method="post"
  action="http://www.mihanblog.com/web/signin/index/atrty/1282722118/avrvy//key/f5224dc9066b9f05c83d1df787019e69/">
<div class="form-row clearfix">
    <label class="" for="address">address</label>
    <input type="text" name="data[address]" id="address" value="" class="english">
</div>
        
<div class="form-row clearfix">
    <label for="username">username</label>
    <input type="text" name="data[username]" id="username" value="" class="english">
</div>

<div class="form-row clearfix">
    <label class="" for="userpass">userpass</label>
    <input type="password" name="data[userpass]" id="userpass" value="" class="english">
</div>
        
<div class="controls clearfix">
    <input type="hidden" name="secfrdcodedvar" id="secfrdcodedvar" value="c7475daec89cff9e98336f3864b164c0">
    <input type="submit" value="11" class="btn" style="width:80px">
</div>
            
        <input type="hidden" name="frm-id"value="12827221184c74c9466e522" id="frm-id"></form>
```

Comment: Where's the cURL issue here? You haven't closed your form tag.

Comment: i mean how to use an iput has no name to assign it with curl

Comment: Hi Moustaf:
How did you solve this issue then?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider checking traffic with tools like Wireshark. It will help you understand how HTTP works and how to particular form works. Then try to replicate it with cURL and you'll be able to see the differences